# Phusion Passenger on cPanel (Apache) "Cannot GET" (Express); the same code works on localhost and Heroku

Tags: node.js, express, cpanel, passenger

My Nodejs app works well on localhost & Heroku, but fails on my cPanel hosting with Phusion Passenger (CloudLinux).

When I look in the node_modules folder, express is there.

Does anyone know how to get my app up and running?

This is the error log:

````
App 1268608 output: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:775
App 1268608 output:     throw err;
App 1268608 output:     ^
App 1268608 output: 
App 1268608 output: Error: Cannot find module 'express'
App 1268608 output: Require stack:
App 1268608 output: - /home/futur/w2/server.js
App 1268608 output: - /opt/passenger-5.3.7-9.el7.cloudlinux/src/helper-scripts/node-loader.js
App 1268608 output:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:772:15)
App 1268608 output:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:677:27)
App 1268608 output:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:830:19)
App 1268608 output:     at Module.require (/opt/passenger-5.3.7-9.el7.cloudlinux/src/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:80:25)
App 1268608 output:     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:68:18)
App 1268608 output:     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/futur/w2/server.js:1:17)
App 1268608 output:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:936:30)
App 1268608 output:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:947:10)
App 1268608 output:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:32)
App 1268608 output:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:703:12) {
App 1268608 output:   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
App 1268608 output:   requireStack: [
App 1268608 output:     '/home/futur/w2/server.js',
App 1268608 output:     '/opt/passenger-5.3.7-9.el7.cloudlinux/src/helper-scripts/node-loader.js'
App 1268608 output:   ]
App 1268608 output: }
App 1271723 output: app is running on port 3002
App 1400344 output: app is running on port 3002 ```
````

Comment: Adam, if you see line 5, "Error: Cannot find module 'express'". It says 'express' is not found. Most probably it is not installed. Make sure that you run 'npm install' or 'yarn install' first.

I've never used the software you have mentioned, but here is a small tutorial: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/nodejs/

Comment: Thanks Faheem, I'll look into the walkthrough from your link. But it looks like express is installed - it's there in the node_modules folder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved the issue - the problem with Phusion Passenger is that the root path isn't '/', it's '/yourAppURL' (in my case '/w2' (https://futuristicon.com/w2/).

Really weird, since root is '/' with all other environments (as I mentioned in the question - app worked flawlessly on Heroku & localhost env).

**Important**: routes others than root won't work out of the box. You will have to, for some reason, manually create an empty folder named the same as your route parameter, inside the folder in which your .htaccess lives.

For example, if you wanted to make a route like this:

```
app.get('/w2/signup', (req, res) => {
res.send('Signup!')
})
```

You would have to create a new folder named signup (not the application root folder, but the folder of your app's URL)

Comment: Thank you I spent hours on this problem and the folder creation solved it

Comment: Wow you are a hero and have saved me a few days of trying to figure out why my routes wouldn't work. New folder creation solved it for me too!

Comment: I love you ! This works perfectly !