# Namecheap shared hosting, Express.js, and app.get() gives "cannot GET /path" error

Tags: node.js, express, passenger, namecheap

I am following the tutorial here: https://socket.io/get-started/chat/

The code works locally but when I upload/Install it to my Namecheap shared hosting server, I get this error displayed in my browser:

> Cannot GET /PathToApp

I have isolated the problem to:

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html"); });
```

since I have another app that works fine locally but won't work when uploaded to Namecheap.

Also, there are no entries in the passenger logs.

Is there a setting I should be changing to get this to work?

Comment: How do you have your port setup?

Comment: Hi. I'm not sure how to do that in Namecheap shared hosting servers but I did figure out how to fix the problem. I've posted it below. (I still want to know how setup ports in Namecheap).

Comment: In your code where you declare your port you should do `const port = process.env.PORT || 3000` so if a port is provided by Namecheap it'll apply it automatically as an environment variable

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, I have to set it up as:

```
app.get("/uriToApp", (req, res) => {
res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html"); });
```

for app.get() to work.

This post helped:
[Phusion Passenger on cPanel (Apache) "Cannot GET" (Express); the same code works on localhost and Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60211699/phusion-passenger-on-cpanel-apache-cannot-get-express-the-same-code-works)